# Enabling flutter web disables all emulators

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When i add flutter web support to a project, any other option like, for ex. launch app on android emulator dissapears(in vs code).
I have not found any sign of trace on official docs about it. It's a bug or there is a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you see the list of available devices when you click "Run > Run without debugging"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to disable web support again to start coding for android/ios. You can do that by this command in your cmd : `flutter config --no-enable-web`

Comment: I know. This does not answer my question.

Comment: I've never had to do this.  I leave everything enabled everywhere, and it works fine from command line and from IDE (VSC).